# How get selected value in bootstrap V5 select with python

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-5

I am using `Class Based Views` in django... Then my model is:

models.py

```
class Survey(Base):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=50, unique=True)
    item1 = models.CharField('Item1', max_length=50)
    item2 = models.CharField('Item2', max_length=50)
...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Survey'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

Now I am reading database data for fill in select and works fine.

**How I get this select item for fill table fields?**

info.html

```
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card card-chart">
            <div class="card-header ">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
                        <h2 class="card-title">Informations</h2>
```

```
                        <option selected>choose a option</option>
                            {% for s in survey  %}
                                <option>{{s.description}}</option>
                            {% endfor  %}

                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- of course, in this moment variable [s] not exist  -->
                    <div class="col-sm-8 text-right">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>item 1</td>
                                    <td>item 2</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- want fill this fields with select item above-->
                                    <td>{{s.item1}}</td>
                                    <td>{{s.item2}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import Survey

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['survey'] = Survey.objects.all()
        return context
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add **value** attribute to the options that you create in HTML.

---

If you want to use the value somewhere else you can follow the procedure below:

You get the **Select** element by giving a specific id to it and retrieve its value.

You can get the element by using `var el = document.getElementById("#id_of_select")`.

By using `el.value` you can get the selected value for select.